# Extracting the current value of an instance variable while walking an Expression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I am currently trying to write some code which turns C# Expressions into text.

To do this, I need to not only walk through the Expression tree, but also evaluate just a little part of it - in order to get the current value of a local variable.

I am finding very hard to put into words, so here is the pseudo-code instead. The missing part is in the first method:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void DumpExpression(Expression expression)
    {
        // how do I dump out here some text like:
        //      set T2 = Perform "ExternalCalc" on input.T1
        // I can easily get to:
        //      set T2 = Perform "Invoke" on input.T1
        // but how can I substitute Invoke with the runtime value "ExternalCalc"?
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myEvaluator = new Evaluator() {Name = "ExternalCalc"};
        Expression<Func<Input, Output>> myExpression = (input) => new Output() {T2 = myEvaluator.Invoke(input.T1)};

        DumpExpression(myExpression);
    }
}

class Evaluator
{
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public string Invoke(string input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Never intended to be implemented");
    }
}

class Input
{
    public string T1 { get; set; }
}

class Output
{
    public string T2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have started investigating this using code like:

```
        foreach (MemberAssignment memberAssignment in body.Bindings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("assign to {0}", memberAssignment.Member);
            Console.WriteLine("assign to {0}", memberAssignment.BindingType);
            Console.WriteLine("assign to {0}", memberAssignment.Expression);

            var expression = memberAssignment.Expression;
            if (expression is MethodCallExpression)
            {       
                var methodCall = expression as MethodCallExpression;
                Console.WriteLine("METHOD CALL: " + methodCall.Method.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("METHOD CALL: " + expression.Type.Name);
                var target = methodCall.Object;

                // ?
            }
        }
```

but once I get to that MethodCallExpression level then I am feeling a bit lost about how to parse it and to then get the actual instance.

Any pointers/suggestions on how to do this very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing expression trees is... complex and time-consuming. Here's a **very incomplete** version that just-about handles your example. In particular, note that we need to:

- hard-code to Evaluator, since "ExternalCalc" is not part of the expression
- manually evaluate some of the tree

Output:

> a new Output set T2 to: call ExternalCalc on get myEvaluator from capture-context with input = get T1 from @input

Code:

```
private static void DumpExpression(Expression expression)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    Walk(expression, sb);
    string s = sb.ToString();      
}
static object Evaluate(Expression expr)
{
    switch (expr.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Constant:
            return ((ConstantExpression)expr).Value;
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            var me = (MemberExpression)expr;
            object target = Evaluate(me.Expression);
            switch (me.Member.MemberType)
            {
                case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field:
                    return ((FieldInfo)me.Member).GetValue(target);
                case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property:
                    return ((PropertyInfo)me.Member).GetValue(target, null);
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(me.Member.MemberType.ToString());
            }
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(expr.NodeType.ToString());
    }
}
static void Walk(Expression expr, StringBuilder output)
{
    switch (expr.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.New:
            var ne = (NewExpression)expr;
            var ctor = ne.Constructor;
            output.Append(" a new ").Append(ctor.DeclaringType.Name);
            if(ne.Arguments != null && ne.Arguments.Count != 0)
            {
                var parameters = ctor.GetParameters();
                for(int i = 0 ;i < ne.Arguments.Count ; i++)
                {
                    output.Append(i == 0 ? " with " : ", ")
                          .Append(parameters[i].Name).Append(" =");
                    Walk(ne.Arguments[i], output);
                }                    
            }
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Lambda:
            Walk(((LambdaExpression)expr).Body, output);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Call:
            var mce = (MethodCallExpression)expr;

            if (mce.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Evaluator))
            {
                object target = Evaluate(mce.Object);
                output.Append(" call ").Append(((Evaluator)target).Name);
            }
            else
            {
                output.Append(" call ").Append(mce.Method.Name);
            }
            if (mce.Object != null)
            {
                output.Append(" on");
                Walk(mce.Object, output);
            }
            if (mce.Arguments != null && mce.Arguments.Count != 0)
            {
                var parameters = mce.Method.GetParameters();
                for (int i = 0; i < mce.Arguments.Count; i++)
                {
                    output.Append(i == 0 ? " with " : ", ")
                            .Append(parameters[i].Name).Append(" =");
                    Walk(mce.Arguments[i], output);
                }
            }
            break;
        case ExpressionType.MemberInit:
            var mei = (MemberInitExpression)expr;
            Walk(mei.NewExpression, output);
            foreach (var member in mei.Bindings)
            {
                switch(member.BindingType) {
                    case MemberBindingType.Assignment:
                        output.Append(" set ").Append(member.Member.Name)
                            .Append(" to:");
                        Walk(((MemberAssignment)member).Expression, output);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException(member.BindingType.ToString());
                }

            }
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Constant:
            var ce = (ConstantExpression)expr;
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(ce.Type, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)))
            {
                output.Append(" capture-context");
            }
            else
            {
                output.Append(" ").Append(((ConstantExpression)expr).Value);
            }
            break;
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            var me = (MemberExpression)expr;
            output.Append(" get ").Append(me.Member.Name).Append(" from");
            if (me.Expression == null)
            { // static
                output.Append(me.Member.DeclaringType.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                Walk(me.Expression, output);
            }
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Parameter:
            var pe = (ParameterExpression)expr;
            output.Append(" @").Append(pe.Name);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(expr.NodeType.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of a MemberInitExpression? Like getting a class with all properties filled? Thanks

Comment: @BarbarosAlp can you define what you mean by the value of an expression? Do you mean "evaluate what value would have been assigned to each member"? or do you mean "run the initializer and give me back the populated object"? or...? both are possible - just use the relevant piece of the expression as the input to a `LambdaExpression` using the same parameters (to avoid having to shim them), compile it, and execute it... (`var result = lambda.Compile().Invoke(args);`). A concrete example would go a long way here...

Comment: I am trying to get VideoInput class with values from this: var cacheKey = CacheKeyHelper.GetCacheKey<IVideoService>(m => m.VideosById(new VideoInput { CategoryId = 123, Name = "Foo" }));

I am working on your suggestion now, thanks.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(p, typeof(object))).Compile().Invoke()

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're wondering how to get properties from the instance of the object the method in your example was being called on.  As Marc mentions in his answer, expression trees are complex and time consuming to work with, this addresses specifically your example (and likely nothing else).

```
    private static void DumpExpression(Expression expression)
    {
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;

        if(lambda != null)
        {
            DumpExpression(lambda.Body);
            return;
        }

        var init = expression as MemberInitExpression;

        if(init != null)
        {
            foreach(var binding in init.Bindings)
            {
                var assignment = (MemberAssignment) binding;
                DumpExpression(assignment.Expression);
                return;
            }
        }

        var methodCallExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;

        if(methodCallExpression != null)
        {
            //Create a func that retrieves the real value of the object the method call
            //   is being evaluated on and get the Name property from it
            var objectGetExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Evaluator>>(methodCallExpression.Object);
            var objectGetFunc = objectGetExpression.Compile();
            Console.WriteLine(objectGetFunc().Name);
            return;
        }
    }
```