# binding to an indexed property in mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to use this binding:

```
var index = 0;
set.Bind(view).For(s => s.DataContext).To(vm => vm.NewsFeedItems[index]); //NOK :(
```

where index is a constant.

But that does not work : it does nothing at all, the values are not displayed. And there is no error in the traces.
What is the correct syntax to bind this property ?

There are other stackoverflow questions about that, and it seems it should work.

I've tryed the same binding with a constant index, and it work! So there is something wrong with the index expression.

```
 set.Bind(view).For(s => s.DataContext).To(vm => vm.NewsFeedItems[0]); //OK !
```

---

EDIT: found a workaround.

```
set.Bind(view).For(s => s.DataContext).To("NewsFeedItems["+index+"]"); //OK !!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the fluent expression parser in MvvmCross.

The MvvmCross fluent bindings only accept constant expressions currently.

So these variants are supported:

```
 vm => vm.Name
 vm => vm.NewsFeedItems[0]
 vm => vm.Foo["Bar"]
 vm => vm.Child.GrandChild.Name
 vm => vm.Children[12].Name
 vm => vm.Lookup["Fred"].Neighbours[3].House.Name
```

but any dynamic expressions - like the one including an `index` local variable **aren't** supported.

Building a full expression evaluator is possible, but requires more complicated code and processing - e.g. see some sample code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13083397/373321 which was a question I asked for a non-MvvmCross project (it was actually for a Hadoop project). There are suggestions to extend MvvmCross fluent binding further - e.g. to include variable evaluation and Tibet type expressions too - but no-one has sent a pull request for this (yet!)

Comment: Ok, this limitation should be written in the wiki ! In which mvvmcross file is the expression evaluator ? I'll have a look at it. I wrote one for sql some years ago.